# Serve Local Files in ASP.NET in Chrome

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Chrome has a setting that blocks the opening of local files. The specific error you get is `Not allowed to load local resource: file:///<file name>`. I'm trying to develop an internal site for us to access these files but as many users are using Chrome, I need a workaround to serve these files.

Currently, to get my files and display them, I have this logic:

```
For Each file As String In Directory.GetFiles("<file path>")
    fileInfo = New FileInfo(file)
    fileList.Add(fileInfo)
Next

fileList.Sort(Function(x, y) x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name))

For i As Integer = 0 To fileList.Count - 1
    pnlLinks.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<br />"))
    pnlLinks.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<a href=" & fileList(i).FullName & " class=""doc-links"">" & fileList(i).Name & "</a>"))
    pnlLinks.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp"))
    pnlLinks.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<span>" & GetByteSize(fileList(i).Length.ToString) & " </span>"))
    pnlLinks.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<br />"))
Next
```

The `a href` is a little funky because I've been experimenting with different folder structures to get this working, but it should not be relevant.

I had the idea of implementing a function that could send this to a byte stream but I'm not experienced in that area and wouldn't be sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this with a `FileStream` and launching to a new page that handles it on `Page_Load`

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim pdfFileStream As FileStream = Nothing
    Dim pdfFileSize As Long = 0
    Dim pdfPath As String = "<file path>"

    pdfFileStream = New FileStream(pdfPath, FileMode.Open)
    pdfFileSize = pdfFileStream.Length

    Dim Buffer(CInt(pdfFileSize)) As Byte
    pdfFileStream.Read(Buffer, 0, CInt(pdfFileSize))
    pdfFileStream.Close()

    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
    Response.OutputStream.Write(Buffer, 0, pdfFileSize)
    Response.Flush()
    Response.Close()
End Sub
```